# `puma:restart' invoke twice but i only call it once on my deploy app via Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I tried to deploy Rails app to the server via Capistrano.
This is my code on deploy.rb

```
set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:varisdaOfficial/insurance_site.git'
set :application,     'insurance_code'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :linked_dirs, %w(public/uploads)

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  desc 'clear temp cache'
  task :clear_cache do
    on roles(:app) , in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
      execute "rm -rf #{shared_path}/tmp/cache/[^.]*"

    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :clear_cache
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end
```

So when i ran 'cap production deploy' everything work smoothly my site can be deployed successfully but i got a message after that.

```
Capistrano tasks may only be invoked once. Since task `puma:restart' was previously invoked, 
invoke("puma:restart") at/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano3-puma-1.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/puma.rake:134 will be skipped.
If you really meant to run this task again, first call Rake::Task["puma:restart"].reenable
THIS BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE IN A FUTURE VERSION OF CAPISTRANO. Please join the conversation here if this affects you.
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1686
```

I just only call restart task once.
So how can i fixed this message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assume you are using the capistrano3-puma gem. That gem automatically restarts puma for you at the conclusion of a successful deployment. So that is the first time the restart task is being called.

Additionally, in your deploy.rb, you've defined your own custom restart task, and you are invoking it `after :finishing`. That is the source of the second invocation, and thus the warning.

To "fix" this problem, remove the redundant task:

```
desc 'Restart application'
task :restart do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    invoke 'puma:restart'
  end
end
```

And remove this:

```
after  :finishing,    :restart
```

Comment: The answer of Matt is the right one. But just for the people that need their Capistrano tasks run twice, you can call the task with invoke! instead.

Comment: I found that if I skipped the second restart task, the app actually failed to start. Is there a way to skip the first one and only keep the second one?